# Local time zone not correct

Tags: php, timezone

I am having some trouble getting the local timezone for the user in PHP.
The website has to reach out to multiple timezones, so setting a static timezone wont work.

So if i do `date_default_timezone_get();` it is off by two hours at my timezone (Copenhagen).

I have looked here on Stackoverflow and on Google, and there are tons of threads that kind of gets around to this problem, but none that fix this in an easy and convenient way, and my guess is that there must be some sort of way to come around this in a convenient way.

As this has to do with registering time usage, it is crusial that this works. Until now I have simply hardcoded the timezone to be Copenhagen, but since this is about to reach launch this has to get the exact time of the user.

Comment: That is probably because your server is located outside of Copenhagen.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. As you've said, there are lots of other Stack Overflow questions about detecting the user's time zone, so you should use one of those answers. Basically it will require Javascript, because it's the *client* time zone that's relevant. I don't see the logic of "none of the answers is simple, therefore there must be a simple way".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has no access to the timezone of the user. You could conceivably fetch it via JavaScript or make an attempt to do it by geoIP on their IP address, but this can be clunky and prone to error.

Your best option, and the one generally adopted by major players like Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc., is just to ask the user for their timezone if dates must be displayed in it. Some sites also take the approach of showing dates as "5 hours ago" instead of a date/time.